# ButtonGroup with NativeButton

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have a ButtonGroup which works with standard vaadin buttons, but I need to use the NativeButton class which inherits Button. The problem is if I use NativeButton the buttongroup isn't rendered.

Working:

```
Button b = new Button();
buttonGroup.addComponent(b);
```

Not working:

```
Button b = new NativeButton();
buttonGroup.addComponent(b);
```

Any idea how can I make ButtonGroup work with NativeButton?

Vaadin version: 7.1.1

Comment: Are you talking about the ButtonGroup addon as available from here: https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/buttongroup?

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Investigating the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/peterl1084/vaadin-7-buttongroup), it shows that native buttons are supported on the "server side" of the ButtonGroup component (as `NativeButton` is a sub-class of `Button`), but **not** on the "client side"; see line 53 of [here](https://bitbucket.org/peterl1084/vaadin-7-buttongroup/src/877c66deab82/src/org/vaadin/peter/buttongroup/client/ButtonGroupConnector.java).

Here, the widget is casted to `VButton` without prior checks; however, in case of a native button, this would have to be `VNativeButton`. As there is no sub-class relationship between VButton and VNativeButton, this will probably cause errors on the client side.

This is clearly a bug of the ButtonGroup; I suggest to either fix it yourself, report the bug to the author, or create a ButtonGroup-like component by yourself. It is, after all, mostly about styling.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This is clearly the case, I will make the neccessary changes to the code.